# What is `userId` in usersnap `user` object?

Tags: usersnap

https://help.usersnap.com/docs/api-for-usersnap-rating-project#setting-default-values-when-initializing-the-widget

I want to send `studentId` in usersnap feedback, I see that we can pass `userId` inside `user` object, but I didn't see it in the account inbox page when feedback submitted, only email is displayed there.

```
window.onUsersnapCXLoad = function(api) { 
    api.init({
      user: {
        userId: "123",
        email: "christina@usersnap.com",
      },
    });
  }
```

What is the purpose of `userId` if it's not displayed in the account inbox page? How can I send a studentId?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `onUsersnapCXLoad` function right after initialising the api object.

```
api.on('open', function(event) {
    event.api.setValue('custom', {studentId: '1234'});
});
```

For a specific project you need to subscribe to the `open` event to set custom values.

Note: There is a project-specific API and global API for Usersnap projects. see the [help page](https://help.usersnap.com/docs/api-for-usersnap-rating-project#advanced-installation---project-specific-snippet) for more information.